# JavaScript image is not changing

Tags: javascript, html

My aim is that when clicking the image it changes to another immediately. The user can click for how many times he or she wants and the image keeps changing. However when I click the image nothing happens.

```
alert("Hey, I'm alive");
window.onload = function () {
    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.getHours();

    var greetingSpan = document.getElementById('greeting');

    if (time < 12) {
        greetingSpan.innerText = "Good Morning!"
    }
    else if (time < 18 && time > 12) {
        greetingSpan.innerText = "Good Afternoon!"
    }

    else {
        greetingSpan.innerText = "Good Night!"
    }

var image = document.getElementById('welcomeImg');

image.onclick = function () {
    var imgSrc = image.getAttribute('src');
    if (imgSrc === 'images/image1.jpg') {
       var imgSrc = image.setAttribute('src', 'images/image2.jpg');
    }
    else if (imgSrc === 'images/image2.jpg') {
       var imgSrc = image.setAttribute('src', 'images/image1.jpg');
    }
}
};
```

This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <?php include('head.php') ?>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <?php include('menu.php') ?>

        <h1>Welcome to T-Shirts Inc. <span id="greeting"> </span></h1>
        <h2>This site is still under construction</h2>
        <p>
            <img src="images/image1.jpg" id="listImage"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eu
            porta purus. Fusce ut ornare est. Nulla eget urna eget massa malesuada condimentum. Aenean aliquet dictum sem
            at sagittis. Sed in ante blandit, ornare nisi quis, molestie velit. Nullam metus risus, convallis id est sed,
            tincidunt consectetur purus. Nulla vitae leo ultricies, consectetur mi vel, fermentum quam.
        </p>
        <p>
            Sed hendrerit metus at sodales suscipit. Integer tincidunt sapien vitae ligula dignissim ullamcorper. Donec eget euismod
            nibh, a ultricies velit. Nam eu pulvinar lacus. Integer ornare nunc sed leo tempor lobortis. Maecenas ut erat
            sit amet purus rhoncus luctus id vitae neque. Etiam rhoncus lacus enim, quis sollicitudin est volutpat ut. Fusce
            at erat at mauris euismod convallis non faucibus lacus. Sed lobortis quis enim elementum placerat. Cras iaculis
            luctus est in sollicitudin. Nam gravida quam eu suscipit facilisis. Morbi ut elementum dolor. In ligula massa,
            iaculis nec risus in, tincidunt malesuada ipsum. Vivamus dictum facilisis lacus eu aliquam. Donec eleifend diam
            magna, sit amet mattis arcu bibendum quis. In cursus feugiat sem nec ullamcorper.
        </p>
        <p>
            Cras venenatis ligula et tortor auctor ultrices. Phasellus ipsum nisi, blandit at eleifend ut, volutpat ut neque. Praesent
            aliquet eu massa ut tristique. Sed sed justo vitae eros imperdiet tempor. Integer mollis mi id hendrerit ullamcorper.
            Curabitur vel ipsum ligula. Suspendisse eget libero velit.
        </p>
        <script src="scripts/behaviour.js">
            type = "text/javascript"

        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it even getting into the function?

Comment: You need to trigger the `onclick` event from the html file.

Comment: I am sorry I'm a beginner in this, can you explain to me how to trigger it please

Comment: Ok I fixed it :) Thank you for your assistance